# MySQL MATCH AGAINST when searching e-mail address

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

In my project, I have use Fulltext index [innoDB engine] for emails search

But didn't receive the proper solution

I have the contacts like

```
user@abc.com
user1@abc.com
user2@abc.com
user3@abc.com
user4@abc.com
```

and

trying fetch the emails

`select * from ContactInfo where MATCH (EMAIL) AGAINST ("user" WITH QUERY EXPANSION) limit 10;`

and only get "user@abc.com" row. but I want to fetch all the rows like "user%"

Experts please give the solution.

Comment: If you are open to an alternative, `REGEXP` could made to work here: `WHERE email REGEXP 'user[0-9]*'`.

Comment: not only user + numbers text also include after user

Comment: I give example only, but i want to search emails like "%search string%" with efficient  way.